# Group buttons and change icon color on active selection

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have a few buttons inside a `VStack()` which I want to bind or combine with one state property, to determine when each button was clicked.

When a button is clicked, I want to use the `.accentColor` modifier while the action is active and when the action is done, fallback to the original `Color.secondary`.

**Currently, here is what it's doing**:

```
- When app is opened, it loads the default color.
- When one button is clicked, it turns both buttons into a lighter shade of gray.
- When I exit the view, it turns both buttons to accentColor and keeps them like that.
- When I click on a button again, it turns gray.
```

**Video for reference**:
https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-d53f89a9af.gif

Could anyone spot what I might be doing wrong?

**So I have the following code** (*Code has been stripped of all the unnecessary items, such as var body: some View, etc..*):

```
@State private var tappedActiveMapAnnotationButton : Bool = false

VStack {
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation(.spring()) {
            self.tappedActiveMapAnnotationButton = true
            mainViewModel.showFilters.toggle()
        }
    }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
            .font(.title3)
            .padding(10)
            .foregroundColor(tappedActiveMapAnnotationButton ? .accentColor : Color.secondary)
    }) //: Button
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation(.spring()) {
            self.tappedActiveMapAnnotationButton = true
            showMapDisplaySheet.toggle()
        }
    }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "map")
            .font(.title3)
            .padding(10)
            .foregroundColor(tappedActiveMapAnnotationButton ? .accentColor : Color.secondary)
    }) //: Button
    .sheet(isPresented: $showMapDisplaySheet) {
        MapDisplaySheetView()
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.25)])
    }
} //: VStack
.background {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
        .fill(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
}
```

Comment: So when you tap on a button on the VStack on the top right, you want the color to indicate selection while the sheet is up, and to revert back to what it was originally when the sheet dismisses?

Comment: @KhoiNguyen, I would like the accentColor color to indicate selection when `sheet` or the `mainViewModel.showFilters.toggle()` is displayed, then go back to original when the `sheet`/`mainViewModel.showFilters.toggle()` is dismissed, that is correct.

Comment: Exactly what you referenced too in the comment, but I wanted to see if it's even possible with just one state variable.

Comment: Can you quickly add `.onDismiss` on `MapDisplaySheetView` and see if it will trigger when you dismiss the sheet? If it's possible, I think I can write up a solution that satisfies your problem.

Comment: @KhoiNguyen, one second doing that now.

Comment: I can do the following and it prints out dismiss when I close the sheet:
`.sheet(isPresented: $showMapDisplaySheet, onDismiss: {
                        print("Dismissed")
                    }) {
                        MapDisplaySheetView()
                            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.25)])
                    }`

Comment: check out my answer and let me know if that satisfies your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following enum

```
enum buttonSelection {
    case buttonNone, button1, button2
}
```

and you essentially create a single state variable of the type `buttonSelection` and perform whatever you want based on the current value of `buttonSelection`

```
        @State private var currentSelection : buttonSelection = .buttonNone

        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    self.currentSelection = .button1
                    mainViewModel.showFilters.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding(10)
                    .foregroundColor(currentSelection == .button1 ? .accentColor : Color.secondary)
            }) //: Button
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    self.currentSelection = .button2
                    showMapDisplaySheet.toggle()
                }
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "map")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding(10)
                    .foregroundColor(currentSelection == .button2 ? .accentColor : Color.secondary)
            }) //: Button
            .sheet(isPresented: $showMapDisplaySheet, onDismiss: {
                print("Dismissed")
                currentSelection = .buttonNone
            }) {
                MapDisplaySheetView()
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.25)])
            }
        } //: VStack
        .background {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Khoi, looks like it's getting closer, but when I click on the icon, it produces the following output: https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-041ba40845.gif

Seems like when the sheet is dismissed, it turns green and then back to original (Which I guess makes sense, with the logic we have) - Maybe my logic is a bit off, but I'd like for the icon to be .accentColor when the sheet is active.

Comment: Hmm I see. I think there's a specific color that overrides the foreground color when the color is selected (the very light grey). When you dismiss the sheet, for a brief second that "overriding color" goes away to reveal our selected color, but then the `onDismiss` executes to remove our color.  I'll keep reading and let you know if I can find something, but maybe this has something to do with using the `.accent` modifier (or some other modifier) on the `Image` instead of `.foregroundColor`

Comment: No need @Khoi, you helped enough - I can do some research if needed, I just wanted to double check to make sure I wasn't making any major mistakes and get some small guidance, but it does look like it's almost a native Apple feature where it shades the colors lighter. I will accept your answer as it did help me go in the right direction.